# Please add more choice to post notices

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answer-quality, post-notice

[Answerama](http://answerama.com/) is causing an influx of quickie questions with one-liner answers. I have put up a few post notices on questions, to try to convey that we would like answers with more information. I used the closest post notice I could find ([example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/why-are-people-in-the-duh-vinci-code-so-low-tech)):

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.

I picked it for “We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer”, but the rest is off the mark, and the irrelevant bit about the “Good Subjective, Bad Subjective” post is confusing.

Proposed wording that would be appropriate here:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted.

Comment: It'd be awesome if diamond mods could edit the boilerplate's text for post notices to make them more appropriate for their site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better late than not at all!

We implemented this with a slightly different wording:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

This should now be live across the network.

Answer (score 4):

For the time being, we're turning on [a click-through quality check](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for new answerers - probably stands a better chance of being read than either of these notices, particularly for folks new to the site.

Customizing the post notice(s) might be appropriate for other reasons; feel free to make other suggestions here so the other folks in the SciFi community can look them over and make suggestions as well.